# How to add nonstandard build steps in CMake

Tags: c, cmake, build

For my existing CMake-based project, I want to enable an optimization available from our C compiler.  Unlike most optimizations, this requires running the compiler several more times, either producing or consuming intermediate files.  Specifically for each each C file, it consumes the C file and produces a corresponding intermediate file.  Then the compiler is run and consumes all the intermediate files (perhaps reading them and writing them back out).  Then finally for each C file the compiler translates the C file, also making use of the corresponding intermediate file, to produce an object file.

The compiler vendor provides a sample Makefile:

```
SRCS=src/file1.c src/file2.c src/file3.c
INFS=objs/file1.inf objs/file2.inf objs/file3.inf
OBJS=objs/file1.o objs/file2.o objs/file3.o
CFLAGS=-object_dir=objs -Owholeprogram -Ogeneral -I.

myprog: ${OBJS}
   ${CC} -o myprog ${OBJS}

# first pass
objs/%.inf: src/%.c ${SRCS}
   ${CC} ${CFLAGS} $< -Q

# second pass
qnormalize: ${INFS}
   ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${INFS} -Qnormalize
   touch qnormalize

# third pass
objs/%.o: src/%.c objs/%.inf qnormalize
   ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${INFS} $< -c -Qfinal
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with CMake?  I looked at adding custom targets and dependencies, but I can't see a way to actually do it.

Comment: Is there any documentation anywhere for how this `.inf` system works? Which compiler is this? The solution might be to write a script that you can inject via the `CMAKE_C_COMPILER_LAUNCHER` variable.

Comment: You might consider asking this question on the [CMake Discourse](https://discourse.cmake.org/) since you're much more likely to get a normative answer from the maintainers. Custom commands aren't really equipped to call the compiler twice. If the compiler wrapper approach doesn't work, you might need to dig around in CMake's internal variables.

Comment: `-object_dir=objs` ? What compiler is that?

Comment: @AlexReinking and KamilCuk - This is the Green Hills compiler for RH850, a common embedded microcontroller.  Thanks for the Discourse recommendation, I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way - you seem to be using some compiler not known to me. CMake has to know how to generate dependencies (`-MD -MT` flags to GCC compiler) and what flags to pass, for that you would have to create the whole compiler configuration  for your specific compiler (files like `Modules/Compiler/**-C-DetermineCompiler.cmake` and `Modules/Platform/Generic-**-C.cmake` and other files, where `**` is the name of your compiler).

This may serve as an initial configuration, **if** the compiler is detected by CMake which may help you get started. If the compiler is unknown to CMake, you can just write everything with `add_custom_command` and single `add_custom_target` on the end.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project(test C)

foreach(i IN RANGE 1 3 1)
   # objs/%.inf: src/%.c ${SRCS}
   add_custom_command(
       OUTPUT  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/objs/file${i}.inf
       DEPENDS
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/file1.c
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/file2.c
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/file3.c
      COMMAND
        ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} 
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/objs/file${i}.inf
        -Q
      COMMENT "Generting file${i}.inf"
   )
endforeach()

# qnormalize: ${INFS}
add_custom_command(
      OUTPUT
          ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/qnormalize
      DEPENDS
          ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/objs/file1.inf
          ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/objs/file2.inf
          ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/objs/file3.inf
      COMMAND
          # ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${INFS} -Qnormalize
          ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}
          ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/objs/file1.inf
          ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/objs/file2.inf
          ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/objs/file3.inf
         -Qnormalize
      COMMAND
         ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch 
         ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/qnormlize
)

add_executable(myprog 
   src/file1.c
   src/file2.c
   src/file3.c
)
add_compile_options(myprog PRIVATE
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/objs/file1.inf
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/objs/file2.inf
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/objs/file3.inf
     -Qfinal
)
    
# objs/%.o: src/%.c objs/%.inf qnormalize
#   ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${INFS} $< -c -Qfinal
foreach(i IN RANGE 1 3 1)
   add_file_dependencies(src/file${i}.c
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/objs/file1.inf
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/objs/file2.inf
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/objs/file3.inf
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/qnormalize
   )
endforeach()

# myprog: ${OBJS} #   ${CC} -o myprog ${OBJS}
add_executable(myprog
   src/file1.c
   src/file2.c
   src/file3.c
)
target_compile_options(myprog PRIVATE -Qfinal)
```

Comment: This answer doesn't take into account flags set via target properties or generator expressions and won't be sensitive to changes to `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` that happen later. Together, these issues reduce its reusability. You're also missing an include for `AddFileDependencies`, but it's deprecated since 3.20 anyway... just `set_property(APPEND)` to the `OBJECT_DEPENDS` source file property.